# A compact grid of squares

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

Given the information below, connect the red point to one of the four corners of the grid, with *exactly* six moves.

- **Each move ends on a unique point**
- **Each move, except two consecutive moves, are unique in size.**
- **Each square is of size $1$**
- **No discontinuities (no abrupt changes in direction) and no intersections allowed**
- **Each path of the moves follows the same direction**

---

Move:
$$\frac{\pi*r}{2}$$

[image]

---

**What have you just done?**

Comment: Can you clarify "each path of the moves follows the same direction"?

Comment: @user7868 I just meant that the path of all the moves goes in the same direction, starting from the red point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apologies for the crude drawing but I think the intended solution looks something like this

> [image]

That is

> Six quarter circle segments (as clued by the $\frac{\pi * r}{2}$ in the question), corresponding to radii 1,1,2,3,5 and 8 respectively proceeding in an anticlockwise manner.

What have we just created?

> A [Fibonacci Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral)

Thanks to Daniel Mathias for the correction in the comments.

Comment: Svobanppv fcveny, abg tbyqra.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thank you, my mistake

Comment: Correct, well done!